# Non-rooted MST of directed graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, np-hardness

I've found a problem that boils down to this: I need to find the non-rooted MST of a directed weighted graph. In other words, I need to find the minimal set of edges such that from any one node in the graph you can get to all others.

This is similar to the rooted MST digraph problem, which the [chu-liu](http://www.ce.rit.edu/~sjyeec/dmst.html) algorithm solves quite nicely. My intuition is to calculate the rooted MST for all nodes using chu-liu and then merge each, removing redundancies along the way. However, I don't believe that that would be optimal.

Has anybody been working on this? Can you point me towards some papers that I should read?

Thanks.

Comment: MST means minimal spanning tree, right? What does it mean to have a non-rooted tree?

Comment: I guess "Minimal Spanning Tree" isn't the best term for what I'm looking for - "Minimal Spanning Subgraph", perhaps. Basically, a subset of the edges such that from any node you can get to any other node. Which is the same thing as an MST in an undirected graph, but not in a digraph.

Comment: Minimal spanning subgraph would do the trick. Except that I can remove some edges from it to get an MST, which would be 'more' minimal.

Comment: I would call it the “minimum strongly connected spanning subgraph,” and finding it is NP-complete as Warren Schudy explained in his answer.

Comment: Do a google search of the phrase "minimum strongly connected spanning subgraph" that Tsuyoshi suggested and read the literature you find. There seems to be a fair amount of prior work on this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you aren't looking for a tree, or an arborescence, but rather a minimum weight set of arcs that suffice to keep the graph strongly connected.

Your problem is NP-complete by reduction from Hamiltonian cycle problem. Given an input undirected graph that you wish to find the Hamiltonian cycle of create a directed graph by replacing each edge with a pair of oppositely directed arcs. Give all arcs weight 1. This directed graph has a set of arcs that leave the graph strongly connected with weight at most the number of vertices if and only if it has a Hamiltonian cycle.

You can get a two-approximation by picking an arbitrary root, finding the minimum weight spanning tree with arcs pointing towards the root, finding the minimum weight spanning tree with arcs pointing away from the root, and then unioning the two sets of arcs.

I don't recognize this problem off the top of my head but have you tried looking in the various NP-complete problem directories for it?

Comment: In this problem, you're allowed to visit a vertex as many times as you want. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the Hamiltonian cycle requires you visit each vertex only once. Remove that stipulation, and it's no longer NP-complete, correct?

Comment: This is surprising. Finding an MST would be much more efficient (effectively linear).

Comment: Hamiltonian cycle does require you to visit each vertex exactly once. An equivalent formulation of Hamiltonian cycle is a cycle which visits each of the $n$ vertices at least once and uses at most $n$ edges. This equivalent formulation is helpful for understanding my reduction.

Comment: Yes, but I don't wish to find a Hamiltonian cycle of the underlying directed graph. I'm allowed to visit each vertex more than once. Doesn't that break your reduction? If not, why not?

Comment: Nate: I think you're missing the point. Warren's using Ham cycle for the reduction TO your problem to show NP-hardness. He's not trying to give you an algorithm.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I'm questioning the reduction. My problem allows revisiting vertexes, which means it isn't simply a digraph ham cycle. Warren assumes that to find my cycle I must find the Ham cycle of the underlying undirected graph. This is not the case. The reduction does not hold.

Comment: @Nate: Warren already explained in his answer (and his comment) that an undirected graph G with n vertices has a Hamiltonian circuit if and only if the directed graph obtained from G by replicating each edge in both directions has a strongly connected spanning subgraph with at most n edges.  This claim establishes the correctness of the reduction.  If you reread his explanations and still not convinced, I guess you can ask for a clarification, but to me it seems that you have not understood what he is saying.

Comment: As you say a spanning subgraph may or may not be a Hamiltonian cycle. However a spanning subgraph _of length $n$_ must necessarily be a Hamiltonian cycle. Therefore there is a spanning subgraph of length $n$ if and only if there is a Hamiltonian cycle. If this still doesn't make sense I'm not sure what else to say other than suggesting that you look in some textbook for example NP-hardness proofs, try to write a similar proof for this problem, and if that fails discuss this problem with a theory-minded person face to face.

Comment: The minimal subgraph is not guaranteed to be length $n$, and each vertex can be revisited. We do not know the length of the minimal subgraph, and constructing a graph where the minimal subgraph is greater than $n$ is trivial. My issue isn't that what you're saying doesn't make sense, my issue is that you're giving me solutions to the wrong problem.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you read the literature on the minimum strongly connected spanning subgraph problem (start with a Google search). A quick glance at that literature suggests that that problem is NP-complete and that it is the same as your problem. Please either tell us how your problem differs from the minimum strongly connected spanning subgraph problem, or else locate an NP-completeness proof in the literature, point us to it, and let us know which specific step of the proof you don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

As has been explained repeatedly above, finding the minimum-weight strongly-connected spanning subgraph ("SCSS") of a given weighted digraph is NP-complete, even in the special case when all weights are one and even when you only want to distinguish the case that there is a subgraph of weight n from the case that the optimal weight is larger than n.

However, to follow up on a comment of Warren Schudy: there is a simple polynomial-time approximation algorithm that gets an approximation ratio of 2: choose an arbitrary vertex s, find the minimum-weight arborescence out of s (subgraph that includes a path from s to all other vertices), find the minimum-weight arborescence into s, and take the union of the two arborescences. I believe this idea is due to Frederickson and JáJá, "Approximation algorithms for several graph augmentation problems", SIAM J. Comput. 1981.

Better approximations are known for the unweighted problem e.g. 1.64 by [Khuller, Raghavachari, and Young, SIAM J. Comput. 1995](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.DS/0205040). I don't know of improvements for the weighted version but that may merely indicate that I didn't search hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

@warren sorry mate I couldn't understand your reduction either, it seems to be saying that finding ham cycle in a directed graph is NPC as finding ham cycle in an undirected graph is NPC, which i feel is a bit off the topic.  It would be better if you could rephrase your reduction more clearly.

also this problem is not NP complete as it's a puzzle from facebook, of course I am guilty of assuming that they have a polynomial time solution for it. has anyone solved it yet?

Comment: Read the comments under Warren's answer.

Comment: oh I got it now, it's NPC,